# Dividing recursively with only subtraction --- not being able to handle decimals

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math

I'm practicing my math/algorithm skills and am trying to divide two numbers using only subtraction. I'm pretty close, but I can't seem to handle decimals and I don't know why? In the lowest level of the stack, when I call divide(9,2), I notice that I'm returning "0", when in fact I want to return 1/2 - but without using the division operator... inside the if x is less than y check, should I add that logic in a subroutine? I'm stuck on how to recursively add numbers after the decimal up to three places.

```
    var divide = function(x, y) {
        //the number of times you need to subtract y from x.

      if (y === 0) {
        return 0
      } 
      // if 
      if (x - y === 0) {
        return 1;
      } 
      if (x < y) {
    // if this is the case, get the value of y - x.  ->1
    var diff = y - x;
    console.log(diff);
    // add a zero to the end --> so in our case, 10
    diff = String(diff) + '0';
    console.log(diff);
    diff = Number(diff);
    console.log(diff);
    // is that now divisible by y? is so how many times? in our case, 5 times.
    var decimal = Number(divide(diff, y));
    var number = "." + decimal;
    //so add .5 to it.
    return number;
  } else {
        return (1 + divide(x - y, y)); 
      }

    };

    var modulo = function(x, y) {

      var val = x;
      while (val >= y) {
        val -= y;

      }
      return val;

    };
```

Comment: You'll probably want to also keep track of a remainder in some way.

Comment: yep, I'm updating to include the remainder piece of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you consider this cheating ? There's no dividing or multiplying, the additions have been turned into subtractions, it returns a float, and it uses recursion. However, there is a fair amount of string conversion going on, to concatenate the digits and add the sign and the decimal point.

```js
function divide(x, y, prec) {
    if (y == 0) return NaN;
    var quot = 0, sign = 1;
    if (x < 0) { 
        sign = 0 - sign;
        x = 0 - x;
    }
    if (y < 0) {
        sign = 0 - sign;
        y = 0 - y;
    }
    while (x >= y) {
        x -= y;
        quot = 0 - (0 - 1 - quot);
    }
    quot = (sign < 0 ? "-" : "").concat(quot, prec == undefined && x > 0 ? "." : "");
    if (x > 0) {
        prec = prec || 13;
        if (--prec) {
            for (var i = 9, temp = x; i; i--) x = 0 - (0 - x - temp);
            quot = quot.concat(divide(x, y, prec));
        }
    }
    return parseFloat(quot);
}

alert(divide( 9,  2));
alert(divide( 2,  9));
alert(divide( 9, -2));
alert(divide(-2,  9));
alert(divide(-9, -2));
alert(divide( 0,  9));
alert(divide( 9,  0));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happenning because when x is less than y you will return 0. However, this is exactly the result of division odd number by 2 - in the last step, the algo will attempt to divide 1 by 2. You need to implement logic in this case, rather than simply returning 0.

Comment: yes I identified that in my question. the only thing I can think of is returning x/y....pretty stuck here.

Comment: @devdropper87: You can keep on dividing by adding `0` to the end of the digit (basically multiplying by 10). So your remainder is 1? Add 0 and you get 10, divide by 2 you get 5 so that's after the decimal point so the result is 0.5.

Comment: @slebetman Only subtraction! Multiplying would be cheating :-)

Comment: @m69: You can multiply by subtraction of 2's complement :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're not averse to floating point errors, this will do the trick, and not a `/`, `*` or even `+` in sight.
You can set the precision, but with a few digits more it becomes annoyingly slow.

It works by setting the quotient to x, and then repeatedly removing y tiny parts from x and y-1 tiny parts from the quotient, until x is 0 and quotient is x/y.

```js
function divide(x, y) {
    var sign = x < 0 ^ y < 0 ? -1 : 1;
    x = y ? (x > 0 ? x : 0 - x) : -1; y = y > 0 ? y : 0 - y;
    var quot = x, prec = 0.000001;
    while (x > 0) for (var i = y - 1, x = x - prec; i; i--, x -= prec, quot -= prec);
    return y ? (sign > 0 ? quot : 0 - quot) : NaN;
}

alert(divide( 9,  2));
alert(divide( 2,  9));
alert(divide( 9, -2));
alert(divide(-2,  9));
alert(divide(-9, -2));
alert(divide( 0,  9));
alert(divide( 2,  0));
```